# Ubuntu Server: Have english as language but french as locale?

Tags: server, language-support, locale

I've installed an Ubuntu Server. I preferred to install it in english as the messages are often more easy to find over the internet when I've an issue.

But still, I would like to have the dates/number formats of my country(switzerland, fr_CH).

I didn't found how to NOT change the language but change the locale.

I assume it is possible, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the French locale unless you haven't done so already:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_CH.UTF-8
```

Then update `/etc/default/locale` using this command:

```
sudo update-locale LC_NUMERIC=fr_CH.UTF-8 LC_TIME=fr_CH.UTF-8 LC_MONETARY=fr_CH.UTF-8
```

It will be effective at next login or reboot.

Comment: I tried, but in some application that are deployed on the server(SickRage by example), the dates are still in the en_GB format

Comment: @J4N: Well, if you rebooted and `echo $LC_TIME` outputs fr_CH.UTF-8, then it sounds like bugs in those applications. (Possibly it's possible to set the date format separately in some applications.)